# Why would using eight cameras filming in parallel be an advantage in "budget" 8mm film production in the 1960's in Japan?

Tags: film, processing, reproduction, movie, 8mm

My Movies SE question [What devices are this Japanese director(?) and his coworker looking through? If they are small format cameras, then why four right next to each other?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/119839/45856) includes several references; here's an excerpt from it:

> I ran across this image from the Seattle Film Blog [monday, october 22, 2007; An Introduction to Anthropology: The Pornographers](http://siffblog2.blogspot.com/2007/10/introduction-to-anthropology.html) which includes
>
> > As the title indicates, Mr. Ogata (Shoichi Ozawa) makes dirty movies, but he does many other things besides
>
> Here there is also four devices that now look like small format film cameras, one with what looks like NIKKOREX written on the front.
>
> [image: Seattle Film Blog monday, october 22, 2007; An Introduction to Anthropology: The Pornographers http://siffblog2.blogspot.com/2007/10/introduction-to-anthropology.html "As the title indicates, Mr. Ogata (Shoichi Ozawa) makes dirty movies, but he does many other things besides"]

**note:** Four cameras are shown above, other images in the linked posts show a 2nd photographer with four more.

[@blobbymcblobby's excellent answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/119841/45856) says "duplication", and contains a plethora-and-a-half more references.

But a question under that answer [is raised in comments](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/119839/what-devices-are-this-japanese-director-and-his-coworker-looking-through-if#comment210995_119841):

> Why do you need duplication ?????

Of course it's a commercial endeavor and the point is to sell many copies, but what exactly is it about the circa 1965 8mm film process that would make having eight near-identical originals **a significant advantage?**

Even if the final product was a half-hour in duration, it seems to me that an 8x multiplier would save roughly n×4 hours, where n = 1, 2 or maybe 3 depending on positive/negative flippings which I'm confused about, so asking.

Comment: Probably your question should be asked here: https://video.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @RomeoNinov No, not at all. This question is about photographic emulsion processing circa 1965 and is completely unrelated to electronically captured and magnetically (or electrostatically) stored video. That's why we have the [tag:movie] tag here.

Comment: @uhoh the presence or lack thereof of a tag is no confirmation that a question is on-topic. The community has agreed that questions must be [relevant to still photography](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/a/291) and while I personally disagree with this decision, I don't believe your question currently qualifies as on-topic.

Comment: @osullic ok well you've linked to [Can I ask ***Videography*** related questions?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28/50110) and I'm asking about the physical act of emulsion processing. I'm not seeing any questions about emulsion processing there and there are gazillions here. Why not let your fellow community members have a chance to write an answer before voting to *a priori* prevent them?

Comment: Given that this is Japan, it may have something to do with local laws and the difficulty to get duplicates of a pornographic movie, while merely having a film developed is less of a problem because you can't tell what is on it in advance.

Comment: This predates digital copying, so in order to copy the film cheaply you'd place it into a film reader and then just copy it from one machine to the other. By having four identical films from the camera you can **use an original copy as your master on four separate machines**.

Comment: Just by way of explanation, the meta question I linked to is where the community decided that questions must be relevant to still photography. Any question on moving image photography (whether film-based or video-based) gets referred back to this meta question. (As I mentioned, I personally kind of disagree, but I don't set the rules.)

Comment: @Valorum what's a "film reader" for 8mm stock in 1965? Was film from the cameras negative? Does the film reader print on to the same kind of negative stock, producing a positive image? So they can make thousands of prints eight times faster with eight machines? (image in the linked question shows two people with four cameras each) It's as simple as that?

Comment: @osullic had another question been closed, [Alan Marcus's excellent and well-received answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/88628/50110) would not have been possible. [The general rule is: could this also apply to still photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/157071) My circa 1965 emulsion processing question does also apply to still photography processes (there are still reels, sprockets, chemical baths, etc.) so I think this quesiton is ok and doesn't need to have answers by other community members *a priori* blocked and prevented.

Comment: @osullic see just for example [shooting stills on super 8 (aka, using it like a regular photography camera)](https://www.reddit.com/r/8mm/comments/ufi1qd/shooting_stills_on_super_8_aka_using_it_like_a/?rdt=57098) Oh and pre-closing [Reflected Earth is 1/3 the size of primary Earth in Apollo footage through spacecraft window; why?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/109863/50110) would have blocked three answers that also apply to still photography. As long as the concepts *also apply to still photography* they have value to the still photography community.

Comment: @osullic because my question is about emulsion processing, not moving images. The chemistry and tone reversal (or not) does not know if it's from a moving image or a still image. For this question, moving vs still is a *non-sequitur* or a red herring, depending on whether you like herring or not.

Comment: @Valorum, etc... even speculative explanations are **answers**, and therefore [should be written as answers, comments](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4655/11924). Thanks. =)

Comment: @osullic: see previous comment. Thanks!

Comment: @scottbb - I prefer to save answers for things that are backed up with proof and evidence, not idle speculation from non-specialists.

Comment: @Valorum I understand. But even well-reasoned guesses are answers, and are potentially useful. But the main point for writing answers as _Answers_ is they can be voted on, edited to later correct it or add supporting info, etc. Comments can't.

Answer (score 3):

For their particular situation what would give 8mm film an advantage is that it most likely would have been reversal film. This is a type of film which when developed is already positive, making it immediately useful. Unlike the more common negative film used in still photography and motion picture photography which requires that the original negative image on the film, after processing, needs to then be transferred (duplicated) to another piece of media to create a useful positive image. In the case of still photography the negative image was most commonly duplicated onto photographic paper, the result often being referred to as a "print". In the case of motion pictures the negative image would be duplicated onto another piece of film, creating a film "print", often referred to as an interpositive, which could then be viewed using a film projector or film viewer. This allowed the production team to get an immediate initial impression of shooting results by viewing what was commonly referred to as dailies or rushes.

In the case of reversal motion picture film, which was common in 8mm at the consumer level, and in some cases 16mm at the prosumer or institutional level, the production of "prints" from the original was not required as the processed film was immediately useful for viewing. This was helpful because not all local photo labs were capable of film duplication, which would have been required if the film was shot using negative film. In the 1960's most film processing was done at small local film processing establishments, which were typically only capable of developing film, and in the case of still photography projecting the image onto photographic paper to create prints, as well as multiple prints if requested. Film duplication however was something more specialized.

As a historic example, probably without argument the most famous piece of 8mm film was shot by Abraham Zapruder on November 22nd, 1963 when he inadvertently filmed the assassination of U.S. President John F. Kennedy. Coincidentally this occurred exactly 60 years ago today (this answer was posted on November 22nd, 2023). After meeting with a locally based Secret Service agent, Zapruder agreed to provide the Secret Service with a copy of the film. They went to a local photo lab to have the film processed. Even though the development of the reversal film by the lab produced a useable single copy, the local lab that they went to was not capable of duplicating the film, so they then took the developed film to a commercial film production company in Dallas which was able to make the duplicates.

Reversal film was also popular for still photography, and similar to motion picture reversal film, after being developed the film was immediately usable, and normally placed into a cardboard holder creating what was known as a "slide", which could be viewed in a slide viewer or using a slide projector. However some still photographers preferred reversal film for its particular film qualities even though they planned to use it in the normal methods such as printing onto paper or magazine publishing. However this often created an additional step if the positive image had to be duplicated onto another piece of film to create a negative to be used as a duplication master.

This leads us back to the question of film duplication, which almost always involved multiple intermediate steps, regardless of what type of film was used. As mentioned the camera negative was used to produce an interpositive. This allowed analysis of the color balance and other technical aspects, which could then be corrected when the image was duplicated yet again to another piece of film, known as an internegative. One or more internegatives were then used as masters for creating theatrical prints for distribution. This process could vary, but generally speaking this was the common method.

In the case of the photographers in this film, they apparently saw an advantage in the simplicity of being able to take the completed film to a local neighborhood film lab, or perhaps an acquaintance who had film development equipment, or possibly even developed it themselves, something which was more feasible when using reversal film since no film duplication equipment was required as would be the case if using negative film. And then to avoid the extra steps and perhaps complication of finding a commercial film lab which could produce duplicate copies of their film, they used a clever, or at least unusual method of filming using eight 8mm cameras simultaneously, which after developing gave them the eight copies that they needed.